# how to change git stash pop colors?

Tags: windows, git

I use git on Windows 7.  I just updated my git to 1.8.0 from 1.7.3.1, and one of the first things I noticed was that git stash pop now had some new coloring in the output.
Both modified and untracked files are now red, like this:

[image]

I would like it to stay white like it used to, both because that is what I am used to, and because I consider the color red to be a sign that something went wrong, which it clearly did not in this case.

So, my question is can this be done, and if so how?

I suspect that there could be some config variable controling this but I can not find it.
I don't want to turn all coloring off though, just this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That output is actually from `git status`, which is run by `git stash pop`.

You can disable color for that command by running

```
git config --global color.status false
```

Or you can choose to use different colors for different types of files with:

```
git config --global color.status.untracked yellow
git config --global color.status.added green
```

Other color slots are available as well, check the docs for `git config` and look for `color.status`.

Comment: Thank you @qqx :) I now have these lines in `~/.gitconfig`:  
`[color "status"] \n  
    untracked = cyan \n
    changed = green \n`